# Android - can't change background on button state changed

Tags: android, button, background, state

I have already did a deep research here and tried lot of things without success. Here is my code:

**btn_estoque.xml**

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu_ativo" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu_ativo" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
```

The button code:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/estoque_menu"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_estoque"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/tab_button_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_button_height"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:onClick="estoqueClick"/>
```

In the class:

```
    public void estoqueClick(View v) {
           btnEstoque.setEnabled(false);

           Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), EstoqueActivity.class);
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
           startActivity(intent);
    }
```

What am I missing? When I click the button, the image is changed only while the button is pressed.

EDITED

Could this be some lifecycle problem? The button changes to the image desired, but go back to the original just a moment after.

Comment: Try adding: `<item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_id" android:state_enabled="true"></item>`

Comment: Thanks friend but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the state_pressed false and have the xml like this:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu_ativo" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu_ativo" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
```

Comment: Didn't work because the middle line made the last line unreachable. Then I put it at the last position and didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

**btn_estoque.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu_ativo" />
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu" />
 </selector>
```

and use this in `Button` XML code

```
android:background="@drawable/btn_estoque"
```

Answer (score 0):

is `btn_estoque.xml` even a selector drawable?

Might be overkill, but try changing your selector to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu_ativo"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu_ativo"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu_ativo"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu_ativo"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu_ativo"/>
    <item android:state_active="true" android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu_ativo"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu_ativo"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/estoque_menu"/>
</selector>
```

Go Simple for your testing and try this:

```
btnEstoque.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btnEstoque.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Strange. So your `Button` gets disabled, but it looks like it's enabled?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens and it is really strange. I checked it buy use Toast to show the state and it changed do disabled.

Comment: updated again with a larger selector. I remember having a bug with states, but only on specific devices. This one helped.